# Schengen area visa: flying to Switzerland via Germany

Tags: visas, schengen, switzerland

I am flying to Switzerland via Germany (transit).

1. Which embassy should I contact to get a Schengen visa?
2. Where will I need to pass through the Schengen immigration?

Comment: Also check out [this meta post](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3757/43483) that includes links to most other Schengen visa questions people came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are not going anywhere else other than Switzerland then you should apply for your visa at the Swiss consulate responsible for your place of residence.  If your itinerary involves other destinations then we do not have enough information to know where you should apply.
2. You will pass through immigration in Germany.